# Installation Failed due to Invalid URI? Installs only in debug mode?

Tags: android

What are the possible causes of android failed to install. Invalid URI?  What URI is this referring to and in what way is it invalid?  It works fine in debug mode, but I cannot get it to install outside of debug mode.

Thanks

Comment: can you better describe the scenario in which you see this message?

Comment: Every time I try to run the app in non debug node I see the error.

Answer (score 3):

This error can point to so many different things, and there is many different fixes. To sum those I've gathered:

1. Problems with Eclipse: Clean project, rebuild project, restart eclipse.
2. Invalid characters: Remove any special characters in Eclipse project name. Use only [a-z] and [0-9] not even [ ] (whitespace)
3. Error in included jar: Try without jar and see if it runs, if does fix somehow.
4. Errors in manifest package setup: Right click in eclipse on project -> Android tools -> Rename application package (rename to something similar, you can always rename back).
5. Problems with device: Remove app from device and try re install.

Answer (score 2):

ingyesid above basically means you need to refactor your project name to not include any non en/us characters. This will then change the apk filename which also cannot have accented letters eg; "ÖÄÅåäöééıßç....etc".. (and neither can any 'res' asset" have these). I had this problem recently when doing swedish, make sure project name and all filenames are in ENGLISH chars/nums only.

-You can however set your appname variable in "res/values/Strings" to the proper international chars.

This is either a bug or some shortsightedness on behalf of android devs. :/

Answer (score 0):

not have accents or unusual characters. I had the accent and the name of the apk generated an error when going to install, remove the tick and it worked

Comment: This answer is too short and needs improvement. Please expand on your answer.

Comment: Removing umlauts from the project name and path resolved the issue for me. `adb install` would work just fine when attempting to install an APK which contains umlauts in its name, so it seems to me that this is an Eclipse/ADT issue - i did not investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

/data/local directory has no permissions for writing, executing on "others".

You must use a superuser App and modify permissions for /data/local.

Setting them to rwxrwxrwx will work

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if you have placed inavalid name of the project like **MyAPP_$33**, SO ONLY Letters [a---z] and digits [0,1,2...] are allowed .
***No special characters are allowed during naming the project***