# Application project wont run/debug over device

Tags: eclipse, usb-debugging

I'm building an android app using Eclipse, and when I want to run/debug it on my android device, it wont run, even if it is just a "hello word" project.

The information shown on console tab is:

> "Installation failed due to invalid APK file!"

I'm wondering what was wrong, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread that almost had the same problem with yours: [Eclipse installation failed due to invalid APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998101/eclipse-installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file)

Please apply those solutions first, then get back to me if it's still not fix

Answer (score 0):

You may have made changes to your versions in your Android manifest file. Delete the app from your device and run it again!