# Fails to install apk

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, filenotfoundexception

The first time I try to install the app,it says `Check for errors in your project`.The second time onwards,it says:

```
 Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
```

[2013-11-25 09:10:44 - ScanCard] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-11-25 09:10:44 - ScanCard] Launch canceled!

The output of my logcat is:

```
 AndroidRuntime(18391): CheckJNI is OFF
 dalvikvm(18391): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
 dalvikvm(18391): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
 dalvikvm(18391): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
 dalvikvm(18391): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
 AndroidRuntime(18391): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
 zipro(18324): Zip: EOCD not found, /data/local/tmp/ScanCard.apk is not zip
 asset(18324): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/ScanCard.apk'
 PackageParser(18324): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of  /data/local/tmp/ScanCard.apk
 PackageParser(18324): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
 PackageParser(18324):  at    android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
 PackageParser(18324):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:488)
 PackageParser(18324):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:456)
 PackageParser(18324):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:758)
 PackageParser(18324):  at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:173)
 PackageParser(18324):  at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
 PackageParser(18324):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)  
 PackageParser(18324):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
 DefContainer(18324): Failed to parse package
 ActivityManager(380): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/ScanCard.apk
```

I am not running a custom ROM,I am running stock Jellybean 4.3 on the Nexus.

## EDIT:

Restarting Eclipse fixed my problem

Comment: Where is your AndroidManifest file ? It seems like it cannot find it: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Right where it should be,I have opened it and it contains everything it should,no xml error there

Comment: paste your manifest file code

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with either your manifest file or your included .jar files. You can check [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/nrl9mKjZCrs) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998101/eclipse-installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file) and see which one of these is the cause of your problem.

Comment: restarting eclipse fixed my problem...i guess it had some issues with the tess2 library.